# Do you store Customer Order Info (Customer name, address..) in its status quo & thus acepting duplicated data?

Tags: mysql, logic

Ok, when customer places an order you have to store Customer Name, his address into DB. You have tables: Name & Address & Order

```
Name table
CustID - FirstName - LastName
1 - Tom - Hand
....

Address table
AddressID - CustID - Street - State -Country ...
1 - 1 - Newyork Street - NY - US


Order table (without storing status quo data)
OrderID - CustID
1 - 1

Order table (storing status quo data)
OrderID - CustID - FirstName - LastName - Street - State -Country  
1 - 1 - Tom - Hand - Newyork Street - NY - US
```

So which Order table type do you choose?

Do you choose the Order table without storing status quo data or the one storing status quo data?

I prefer the one storing status quo data, since we need the evident of status quo info of order so that when customer have a problem we can have a fixed data for checking, but then we have duplicated data.

If we choose Order table without storing status quo data, then the data like Name & address may be changed and thus we can't have order with status quo data and that is serious.

So, how does real world project manage this?

Comment: What are you asking? What is status quo data? Why not store *orderId*, *addressId* (which implies *custId*) and *a timestamp*?.

Comment: ok, say if you chose Order table (without storing status quo data) then ur Order Table has only 2 columns right? So if u want to know Name & address of that Order you have to Join with Customer & Address table right? But what if user change that info? At the time they buy the item they live in New york, but later they changed to Cali? but they bought the item in NY?

Comment: @Turn You can make addresses immutable and simply create new ones when customers move. Since addresses have a constraint on the customer (through the *customerId* key) the projection is stable. Usually people have a few addresses (like bill to and ship to). This question then moves to tracking shipments (for example).

Comment: but how real world project handle that issue?

Comment: @Turn tracking shipments? please clarify your question.

Comment: I am talking about Designing DB Structure that can handle this issue properly

Comment: if we make address immutable then we need to lock the row permanently, ie no one can edit that row, we can only insert new row. But then it not easy to make row immutable

Comment: @Turn Do it in your code. As long as your update method creates a new row and tracks the most up to date *address* by *id* you're good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your requirements of course. But you should have the Order table with Name, Address etc. This is not really a "duplicated data" as you think, in this case, it just serves as the order history which is really important in any enterprise system. Orders should reflect the shipping data based on the Name and Address snapshot at the time of order. If the order is shipped, then this may not be editable anymore whereas the Customer's Name, Address etc. can be updated at any time and will be used for future orders.

Please also see a very good reference about this/similar subject [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/timeNarrative.html) (as usual) by Martin Fowler

Comment: +1 . . . You make a very good point about the order history, which people often forget when designing data structures.